# python get output of print(df) to use in PyQt

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pyqt

I want to display the results of `print(df)` in a PyQt QtPlainTextEdit. I mean these kind of results:

```
              date symbol        open  ...         low        high     volume
0       2016-01-05   WLTW  123.430000  ...  122.309998  126.250000  2163600.0
1       2016-01-06   WLTW  125.239998  ...  119.940002  125.540001  2386400.0
2       2016-01-07   WLTW  116.379997  ...  114.930000  119.739998  2489500.0
3       2016-01-08   WLTW  115.480003  ...  113.500000  117.440002  2006300.0
4       2016-01-11   WLTW  117.010002  ...  114.089996  117.330002  1408600.0
...            ...    ...         ...  ...         ...         ...        ...
851259  2016-12-30    ZBH  103.309998  ...  102.849998  103.930000   973800.0
851260  2016-12-30   ZION   43.070000  ...   42.689999   43.310001  1938100.0
851261  2016-12-30    ZTS   53.639999  ...   53.270000   53.740002  1701200.0
851262  2016-12-30    AIV   44.730000  ...   44.410000   45.590000  1380900.0
851263  2016-12-30    FTV   54.200001  ...   53.389999   54.480000   705100.0
```

I have tried:

```
self.data_overview.insertPlainText(df.to_string())
```

but this prints the entire dataset. Is there an easy way to get the summary from the print result?

Comment: With "summary" do you intend the "ellipsis" version you are showing above? Did you try with a simple `str(df)`?

Comment: yes i did not know that was called ellipsis. The str(df) worked thanks!